# Promises and irregular callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, control-flow, bluebird

I'm playing around with a promises control flow, using [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird).  Bluebird provides a .promisify() method for converting a regular callback function into a promise function, but I'm unclear what I should be doing when the function is irregular.  For example the method signature for a [requestjs](https://github.com/mikeal/request) request is

```
request(url, callback)
```

where callback is

```
err, res, body
```

instead of the regular

```
err, res
```

How should I be converting this to a promise?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Promise.promisify()` can work with such callbacks as well. When multiple values are given, they'll just be passed along in an `Array`:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var request = Promise.promisify(require('request'));

request('http://stackoverflow.com').then(function (result) {
    var response = result[0];
    var body = result[1];

    console.log(response.statusCode);
});
```

Which can also be [`.spread()`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#spreadfunction-fulfilledhandler--function-rejectedhandler----promise) back to individual arguments as Esailija mentioned in the comments:

```
// ...

request('http://stackoverflow.com').spread(function (response, body) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
});
```

Comment: You should also be able to use [`.spread(function(response, body){})`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#spreadfunction-fulfilledhandler--function-rejectedhandler----promise) in place of `.then`